# Can we place two gradients one over the other

Tags: css

Following is the linear gradient I have for a div :

```
div{
background: linear-gradient(112deg,#A0148C , #FF2896 37.1%, #F05A00 81.3%);
}
```

Can we place another CSS gradient over this one(like another layer over this gradient)?

Comment: Relevant documentation on **MDN**: [linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) - [Using CSS gradients (Overlaying gradients)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients#Overlaying_gradients) - [Using multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just list backgrounds in the property, separated by commas. Remember there will need to be some transparency in the 'upper' gradient for the 'lower' gradient to be visible underneath:

```
div{
background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,255, 0.5)), linear-gradient(112deg,#A0148C , #FF2896 37.1%, #F05A00 81.3%);
}
```